# What is a set reduced to an element?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, set-theory

I have problem understanding the following sentence in Verdier's paper.

> Ob($\mathcal{G}$) est un ensemble réduit à un élément choisi une fois
> pour toutes.

What is the meaning of this sentence? I think this means a set consisting of two elements so that it reduces to an element once we choose one.

Here is the context of the sentence.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"A set of a single element". For emphasis, he writes that the element is "chosen once and for all". He basically means $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal G)=\{*\}$ for some (fixed) element $*$.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what is going on here is we're looking at a category with a group-like structure.

However, the group-like structure does not lie in the objects of the category, but in its arrows.

The category itself will have a single object. We don't care about what that object is, for it doesn't matter; instead we look at the arrows, and on them have a group structure (wherein the operation is composition).

Each element of the original group is given a corresponding arrow to and from that object, and composition of arrows corresponds to group multiplication, and the resulting product also has an arrow in the associated category.